# Accepting an SVG as a prop to a React component

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am working on a React component that needs to accept an SVG as a prop.

I have a default svg in case the prop is not provided, but if it is provided then the default svg can be replaced out with the one accepted from prop.

So the component is like.

```
<MySvg src={path to svg or the svg itself} height={20} width={20} fillColor={'red'} />
```

All that the component should do is display this SVG with the provided props. I expect the DOM to be something like this.

```
<svg fill={this.props.fillColor} height={this.props.height} width={this.props.width}>
    <g>
        <rect />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Since each SVG is different, meaning it might have a polygon, rect, g, etc., what is the best way to achieve this?

2 things I am looking for?

1. Loading an svg from a path and applying the props (color, height, width)?
2. If src prop has the SVG itself, how do we display that and apply the props (color, height, width)

**Update:** I tried out one of the approach in the answers below, but it does not seem to work. Here is a link to a CodeSandbox I have in place - [codesandbox.io/s/n0yzv9yyvp](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0yzv9yyvp)

Answer (score 2):

I worked with SVG in react.js a lot, the best solution I found is to use embed svg:

```
<MySvg src={'/path/to/svg'} height={20} width={20} fillColor={'red'} />
```

And inside your component

```
<svg fill={this.props.fillColor} height={this.props.height} width={this.props.width}>
  <g>
    <image
      x="10"
      y="197"
      width="159"
      height="113"
      xlinkHref={this.props.src}
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

`x`, `y`, `width` and `height` are usual parameters of the `image` svg tag, you can omit or rewrite them as you want

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried out this approach, as I think this is best suited for my use-case. It didn't work with my code repo.

So, I put together a CodeSandbox; but it does not work as expected there as well - https://codesandbox.io/s/n0yzv9yyvp

Want to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be to use data URIs.

Example:

`<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ... > ... </svg>'>`

Read more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score 0):

you can pass props to svg components just like any other components

for example

```js
function App() {
  return <Svg height={20} width={20} fill={black} />;
}

const Svg = ({ height, width, color }) => (
  <svg
    height={height}
    width={width}
    fill={color}
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  ></svg>
);
```